# any nice addons for firebug

Tags: firebug

I use firebug a lot ,i installed measure it , firecookie. Do you guys know any other nice additions to firebug which can be used during development.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/13-must-have-add-ons-to-strengthen-firebug/) are 13 must-have add-ons to strengthen Firebug.

Comment: I don't know if it's only me, but I'm kind of sick of "must have". There's no way there are 13 things you MUST have. That said, some of those do seem quite useful.

Comment: @Jami Wong, how very Zen of you, but I happen happen to have many needs imposed on me by materialist society and late night infomercials.  Most of all, I need more cowbell.

Answer (score 2):

If you're a jQuery user: http://firequery.binaryage.com/

Answer (score 1):

[CodeBurner for FireBug](http://tools.sitepoint.com/codeburner/) -- HTML/CSS Reference in-browser.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [PixelPerfect](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/7943/). I use it a lot when exact layouts are required (which is what most designers are asking for).

Answer (score 1):

I am using

- **FireRainbow** - syntax highlighter
- **Colorpicker** - color picker
- **MeauseIt** - measure tool
- **FireCookie** - cookie manager
- **FireQuery** - for jQuery development
- **PixelPerfect** - for coding designs as perfect pixel
- [**Illuminations for Developers**](http://www.illuminations-for-developers.com/) - usually I am using this when I code ExtJS, that provides me more detailed information for libraries.
- **CSSUsage** - shows how efficient used CSS Rules
- **Firebug AutoCompleter** - autocompleter for firebug

This is my must have addons. I love Firefox and Firebug with my addons, thanks in advance to its authors.

Comment: Wow, checked out my app http://cssUpdater.com ?   I think it will fit perfectly in your list above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an official page with existing Firebug extensions:
http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions

Honza